# The Value attribute in string-based enumerations when converting to c# object

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

when i use xsd.exe on xsd file which contains this piece:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Primes">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:length value="3"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="5" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="7" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="11" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="13" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="17" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

The following enum type is produced:

```
public enum Primes { 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("5")]
    Item5,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("7")]
    Item7,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]
    Item11,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("13")]
    Item13,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("17")]
    Item17,
}
```

But when i'm validating XMl, it generates error message:

{"Instance validation error: '17' is not a valid value for Primes."}

Probably because she is waiting for the value "Item17" instead. So how can i pick a value of 17 instead of Item17 ?

It won't work just changing Item17 to 17

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you are trying to use an illegal identifier for a C# `enum` value.  This isn't legal and is the source of your problems here.  The simple fix here is to make the values of the enumeration legal C# identifiers in the XML and C# code.  For example use `Item17` everywhere and not `17`.  Then write a helper function to convert from the `enum` values to the numeric ones you desire

```
static int GetNumber(Primes p) {
  switch (p) {
    case Primes.Item2: return 2;
    case Primes.Item3: return 3;
    ...
    case Primes.Item17: return 17;
    default: 
      // Handle bad data, probably throw
      throw new ArgumentInvalidException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, this may work it's not a particular a good solution. The problem is that enum types that contains a series of integers stored as strings.... are by default converted to this "Item1" and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution:

Just give the items a correct value:

```
public enum Primes
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2 = 2,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3 = 3,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("5")]
    Item5 = 5,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("7")]
    Item7 = 7,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]
    Item11 = 11,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("13")]
    Item13 = 13,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("17")]
    Item17 = 17,
}
```

I belive that his is better solution because then you can use the enums in the "client" side in a same way as normal enums. For example:

```
(Primes)Enum.Parse(typeof(Primes), dbreader["col_enum"].ToString())  

 prints out >> 2 instead of item2
```

Consider that when you create a C# object from xsd with xsd.exe, this is by default how the handle integers enum types in xml.

Comment: Thank you!

By default the xsd tool gust generates the likes of

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3

Assigning the integer value does the trick.